# How to insert an image into an alertify.js alert with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, alertify

I want to create a pop-up dialog with a large image and an OK button and for this I'am trying to customize the alerts of [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) .

My idea was to create a custom `css` class for all these "popup-alerts" with an default image url, and then change the url `background-image: url(images/level_10.jpg);` when I create the pop-up to the right image with `JavasScript` (because you can pass in a custom `cssClass` when you call the function);

I'm not sure whether this is possible at all.

Or is there maybe better way to customize alertify.js to achieve this?

Comment: I find `alertify.js` is rather limited in this. Are you open to more established libraries like `jQuery UI`?

Comment: I was thinking about using the bootstrap modal dialogs for pop-ups. but maybe the jQuery UI effects work for the log messages.

Comment: Here is a jQuery UI example: http://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/hGQmw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the CSS class of alertify.

Just look the example below:
http://www.fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/assets/js/lib/alertify/alertify.bootstrap.css

In your case, you just want to override `.alertify` CSS class like this :

```
.alertify.popup1 {
    background: url(path/file1.png);
}
.alertify.popup2 {
    background: url(path/file2.png);
}
/* etc */
```

And use the Javascript like this:

```
$("alert1").onclick = function () {
 alertify.alert("This is an alert dialog", function() {}, 'popup1');
};
$("alert2").onclick = function () {
 alertify.alert("This is an other alert dialog", function() {}, 'popup2');
};
```

[**Check this fiddle for a workin example ;)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjzc4/)

Comment: can I only do this in my custom theme /in the the css file. Or is there a JavaScript function for this?

Comment: You can do this in your own css file ;)
Just be sure your CSS file is placed after the default alertify CSS file

Comment: In the example this is used to change the css: $("toggleCSS").href = "../themes/alertify.bootstrap.css"; My problem is how to change the url afterwards (for each popup).