# styling jquery alertify-plugin

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, alertify

To change the style of the jquery alertify plugin i did the following,
here is the head-part, where all the files are loaded in ( i hope so ) the right order:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="alert/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/onsubmit.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alert/alertify.default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alert/alertify.core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alert/alertify.bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />

</head>
```

this is the onsubmit.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var dump = $("#dump").val();
    if(dump) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(dump)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == 1) {
                    alertify.alert( data.error, function() {}, 'popup1' ); // the first popup styled
                    return false;
                } 
                if(data.result == 0) {
                    alertify.alert( data.error, function() {}, 'popup1' ); // the second popup styled
                    return false;
                }           
            }
        });
    } else { 
        alertify.alert("message");
        return false;
    }

  });
});
```

style.css:

```
.alertify.popup1 {
    background: red;
}
.alertify.popup2 {
    background: blue;
}
```

But alert-box for the received data is still displayed normal and not modified.
I just followed his steps:
[How to insert an image into an alertify.js alert with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104517/how-to-insert-an-image-into-an-alertify-js-alert-with-javascript) , my style.css is included after alertify.css , so anybody could help me with solving my problem? greetings

Comment: You are loading jquery 1.9.1 AND 2.0.3. You should remove one of these. That wont be the cause of your issue though..

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I think it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double jQuery include.

Probably you are not setting the 3rd parameter, used to customize the UI:

> [Optional] Class(es) to append to dialog box

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clicky').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this section?', function(e) {
            if (e) {
            }
        },'popup2');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kBnPy/